# Set default alarm sound programatically Android

Tags: android, alarm

I've been trying to define the default alarm sound but with no success! I can sucessfully change the ringtone and the notification sound but the alarm doesn't change at all... I'm using this code for the alarm:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, Uri.parse(uri+"/"+id));
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the values of the variables `uri` and `id` for the Alarm Ringtone in your statement?

Comment: Absolutely! I use the very same for nofitication and ringtone and they work :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 try {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(),
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
            Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.ALARM_ALERT,
                    newUri.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. :)

Comment: @AditiRawat  what can i do for you?

Comment: Just a short description as to *why* you think this answer would work. This would be udeful for future readers. :)

Comment: Just Because i Use this Code in My Project and It works. :)