# Setting alarm via Uri reference

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

1.How can I get an URI of music file using code above?
2.If I have Uri already, how set it as ringtone or alarm?
Also tried use:
[Convert a file path to Uri in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602986/convert-a-file-path-to-uri-in-android/53349110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a return result from an activity, use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.

```
private int REQUEST_ACTION_PICK = 1;

...

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  // startActivity(intent);
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACTION_PICK);  //fixme

// ...

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACTION_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Uri uri = data.getData();
      Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
    }
  }
```

As for 'how set it as ringtone or alarm?', perhaps this might work?
[Set default alarm sound programatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593690/set-default-alarm-sound-programatically-android)

Comment: uri2 = data.getData(); from on @Override ActivityResult return:
content://media/external/audio/media/174   
But something goes wrong
RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); return null
then I call
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, uri2);
after then I call againg:
RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
And also return null, it shouldn't return sth like content://media/external/audio/media/174  ?

Comment: Paste your logcat. Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

Comment: In button "set song" I do:
   try{
            ringtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getBaseContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, uri2);
            Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ALARM_ALERT,uri2.toString());
            ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri2);
           }catch (Throwable t){
        }
Then in another class whose extends broadcastreciver I call;
ringtone.play();
Then I get an error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.Ringtone.play()' on a null object reference

Comment: Highly possible that the user-supplied uri is the issue. Replace it with the default uri, you should hear something. ```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
ringtone.play();
```
Then work your way backwards to determine why the user-uri is null. At this point, I would also assume that you have taken care of 'WRITE_SETTINGS' permissions required for setting the phone's ringtone.

Comment: Finally I did it like you said. 
But not from Mainactivity. In the another class which extends broadcast_receiver. I put the code above, changed only TYPE_ALARM from TYPE_RINGTONE.
Also in MainActivity declarated uri2 and ringtone as static and it works!
Thanks for your help :D